# How can I make sense of the equation $\mathrm{d}=\mathrm{d}_{\mathbb R^3}+\mathrm{d}t\wedge\partial_t$? Is it valid for 1-forms only?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I need to understand the equation $\mathrm{d}=\mathrm{d}_{\mathbb R^3}+\mathrm{d}t\wedge\partial_t$ (especially the term $\mathrm{d}t\wedge\partial_t$). The author claims that it is valid in Minkowski Space. But I don't understand how to make sense of that formula, if anything only for 1-forms.

Comment: It could be interpreted as $\partial_{t}\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a $p$-form on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ since, I presume, forms on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are spatial (ie don't contain $dt$ terms) but are time dependent (ie the components of the forms are $t$-dependent). So the derivative differentiates the _components_ of a form.

Comment: It's valid for all $k$-forms.

Comment: @AloneAndConfused That's a good point, thank you :)

Comment: @TedShifrin That's because $\mathrm{d}=\mathrm{d}_{\mathbb R^3}+\mathrm{d}t\wedge\partial_t$ is just a special case of $\mathrm{d}=\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ (in more detail, $\mathrm{d}\omega=\mathrm{d}x^i\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\omega_I\mathrm{d}x^I$ if $\omega=\omega_I\mathrm{d}x^I$), right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 2):

I interpret the identity as
$\mathrm{d}f
= \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\cdot\nabla f + \mathrm{d}t\,\partial_t f$
for a function $f(\mathbf{x}, t),$
i.e. $\mathrm{d}_{\mathbf{R}^3} = \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\cdot\nabla$ and $\mathrm{d}t \wedge \partial_t = \mathrm{d}t \, \partial_t$.

Comment: That's a nice observation, thank you :)